# Inserting multiple Array lists into single Array list using java?

Tags: java

how to insert a multiple `ArrayLists` into single `ArrayList`? 
like

- a list has `1,2,3`
- b list has `2,3,4`
- c list has `3,4,5`

final output what i want is `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]`.

Comment: Do you want a list of lists or a list with all items of the single lists?

Comment: Please show next time what you have tried so far, that's how it works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> masterlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> chillist1=
    new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
ArrayList<Integer> chillist2=
    new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2,3,4}));
ArrayList<Integer> chillist3=
    new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{3,4,5}));


masterlist.add(chillist1);
masterlist.add(chillist2);
masterlist.add(chillist3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> combinedList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

combinedList.add(list1);
combinedList.add(list2);
combinedList.add(list3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it in one expression:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
      new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)),
      new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3,4)),
      new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,4,5))
));

System.out.println(listOfLists);
// Output: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> intArrayLst = new ArrayList<>();

    intArrayLst.add(1);
    intArrayLst.add(2);
    intArrayLst.add(3);

    arrayLst.add(intArrayLst);

    intArrayLst = new ArrayList<>();

    intArrayLst.add(2);
    intArrayLst.add(3);
    intArrayLst.add(4);

    arrayLst.add(intArrayLst);

    intArrayLst = new ArrayList<>();

    intArrayLst.add(3);
    intArrayLst.add(4);
    intArrayLst.add(5);

    arrayLst.add(intArrayLst);

    System.out.println(arrayLst.toString());
```